# User defining predeclared global constants

Tags: c++

I'm in a project where we want globally defined constant variables.

At the moment we have a class like

```
class Settings
{
    public:
        static constexpr unsigned int CONSTANT_ONE{1};
        ...
}
```

The problem is some of these constants we would rather have be able to be set *at program start* (as the title states, the user should be able to do this) instead of being predefined in code.

Is there a *nice* way to do this, and still have the variables constant?

Thankful for input, cheers!

Comment: Do you want to be able to vary the values dynamically, i.e. can it be that they are different at every program startup?

Comment: Yes that is the thought, but that they can't be changed while the program is running (the reason we want them const).

Comment: Hm, that's a bit tricky, since you only get access to the command line flags once you're in `main`. You could use the environment (`getenv()`) before `main`, but that's not terribly elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You can place constants at `private` section of class `Settings`, make static getters for them and write static function `Initialize`:

```
class Settings
{
public:

    static bool Initialize();

    static unsigned int CONSTANT_ONE();

    ...

private:

    static unsigned int constantOne;

    ...
};

...

bool Settings::Initialize()
{
    static bool isInitialized = false;

    if (isInitialized)
    {
        // error
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        isInitialized = true;
    }
    constantOne = 1;
    ...

    return true;
}

unsigned int Settings::CONSTANT_ONE()
{
    return constantOne;
}

...
```

You can also define macro to create getters automatically:

```
#define CONSTANT_NAME(Name) my_##Name

#define DECLARE_CONSTANT(Type, Name) \
    public: \
        static Type Name(); \
    private: \
        static Type CONSTANT_NAME(Name);

#define DEFINE_CONSTANT(Type, Name) \
    Type Settings::Name() \
    { \
        return CONSTANT_NAME(Name); \
    } \
    Type Settings::CONSTANT_NAME(Name);
```

Example of using:

```
class Settings
{
    ...
    DECLARE_CONSTANT(unsigned int, CONSTANT_ONE)
    ...
};

...

DEFINE_CONSTANT(unsigned int, CONSTANT_ONE)
```

Comment: I've been contemplating this for a bit, but still a problem exists: the values can still not be constant right? (Meaning constantOne for example) The main point of the question was to still be able to have the variables constant, but be able to initiate them in the execution of the program.

Comment: @pingul You can't modify these variables outside `Settings` class. If something looks like a constant, it is a constant.

Comment: Not in the eyes of the compiler I'm afraid; functions that requires `const` parameters need something that is const. I do see your point of view though.

Comment: @pingul But my static functions return r-value (or you can make them to return constant references)! Can you give an example of the function you are talking about (because I cannot understand what you mean)?

Comment: Try creating a constant CONSTANT_ONE like above, and try using it to do `std::bitset<Settings::CONSTANT_ONE()>` and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: @pingul Of course you can't use my 'constants' in compile-time expressions, you should replace them with run-time ones. If I understand right you want smth like [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) but there are very few languages which support such things.

Comment: Interesting; I did not know _why_ that code didn't work, so thank you for pointing that out. I'm not sure if I grasped what dependent types was, but I think I got what I searched for.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but not quite sure it would serve your need though.

I declare the following string in class private section in header:

```
static const char mod_name[32];
```

I then instantiate it in source like following:

```
const char CLASS_NAME::mod_name[32] = "SOME STRING";
```

Maybe start from this and see how you can pass the value in?

Also, as a private const member, you can instantiate during instance construction which give you a way of passing in such constant values.